# django form invalid after setting it up with a valid instance

Tags: django, django-forms

I am really confused why this form.is_valid() returns False:

Here is the django model I created:

```
class aModel(models.Model):
    some_id = models.IntegerField()
```

I turn the `Model` into a `ModelForm`, and create a `ModelForm` instance with an instance of the `Model`. Shouldn't this `ModelForm` instance be valid?

```
>>> class aModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
...     class Meta:
...             model = aModel
... 
>>> am = aModel.objects.get(id=1)
>>> for k,v in am.__dict__.items(): print k,v
... 
_state <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x1020c8a50>
id 1
some_id 5
>>> form = aModelForm(instance=am)
>>> form.is_valid()
False
>>> am.save()
>>> am.some_id = 6
>>> am.save()
>>>
```

Why isn't the form valid? What do I need to do to make the form valid?

Comment: `form.errors` returns `{}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this form is not bound to data, so it cannot validate. You can verify by printing `form.is_bound()` just before `form.is_valid()` to verify.

If it is not bound, I don't think you can validate. To bind data, you need to add the data as a dictionary for the first argument to the form.

```
form = aModelForm({'some_id': am.some_id}, instance=am)
form.is_valid()
```

See [Django - Forms API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/) for more details.

Comment: I have read the Forms API enough, but your simple answer helps so much in adding that insight which makes everything alot more clear. Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the data should be? I'm not understanding why it needs anything other than my instance.

Comment: Well, I assume you are updating the data for the instance. Just simply getting the instance only assigns the instance to the ModelForm, but doesn't bind the data you are updating/validating from the request POST. You wouldn't validate an instance conforms to a ModelForm when that instance is not being changed in any way. It has already been validated the last time it was saved.