# Django forms lose related data

Tags: django, django-1.4

It appears that there's no way for me to get an ORM object with numerous `select_related` objects and create a `Form` and run my data through all the cleaning and additional validations I have.

I'm simply trying to reduce the number of queries that get executed, the form either takes an `id` and re-creates the object, or does not take advantage of the additional fields (I've tried using `model_to_dict`)

Is there anything I'm missing? How can I use select_related inside of a form?

Django 1.4

Comment: Can you show us the code? How are you making the select_related calls? Also relevant here: which version of django?

Comment: @ThomasOrozco, select_related isn't the problem... main question is how do I pass actual objects into a form, rather than "form data". Updated OP with django version.

Comment: Did not understand that, sorry! See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do:

```
form = MyFormClass(instance=my_object)
```

Your form will need to be a `ModelForm`, [see the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) for more information!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14062197/django-form-invalid-after-setting-it-up-with-a-valid-instance